Why did Gru have to adopt the girls?
In Despicable Me, the super-villain Gru decides to adopt three orphans girls to get access to his nemesis Vector’s house and steal back a shrink ray. The plan is to put cookie robots into the cookies the girls sell to Vector.
Adoption is a big long-term responsibility. It seems odd that a supposed genius would decide he has to adopt girls just for one heist. It would have been much simpler just to sneak the robots into their cookies before they delivered them, or even to just try and pay the girls to help him.
Clearly Gru figured he could just get rid of them or return them after they served their purpose, since he tried to ditch them at the amusement park. But that’s still a lot more work than the alternative. Granted he also clearly didn’t understand what he was getting into, but even just the logistics of applying for adoption are far more complicated than more obvious alternatives.
Is this just a plot hole or can anyone come up with an in-universe explanation? I suppose one simple explanation is that Gru is a bit impulsive and while he’s intelligent in some ways he doesn’t fully consider every option because he’s so focused on achieving his goals.
I imagine they may have cut something that justified him jumping directly to adoption.

Two words: mad genius.

Movie characters have right to not think things through, be illogical or stupid or upset or clueless.

Movie characters have no rights. Script writers certainly are free to create characters who behave in stupid ways, but usually that character trait should be consistent throughout the film or justified for that moment. Gru is established as an evil genius and he had plenty of time to think his plan through and find a simpler method. Still, it's clear that Gru often makes silly decisions, so if one wanted to argue that the answer to the question is simply that he was being stupid, that's perfectly valid, albeit uninteresting.

Shim, buddy, the adoption plan is in service to steal a shrink ray so he can shrink and steal the moon. If we’re taking that seriously, then in the relative scale of “moon voyage”,  “adopting three children” is barely a line item in terms of logistical cost.

You're dramatically overestimating the complexity of Gru's plan. His initial thought is that the girls could remove the shrink ray, possibly with the assistance of cookie-shaped robots. He overhears that they're orphans, which gives him a brainwave about how he can use them as his unwitting accomplices.

EXT: VECTOR'S FORTRESS - SAME
There is a pause. Then-- VHHRRRT. The guns retract and the gates open, allowing the girls to enter.
EXT: STREET - FANTASY
Gru can see the girls carrying out the Shrink Ray.

Note that he has zero interest in their long-term wellbeing, and the adoption process consists of him hacking the orphanage's computer and inputting a fake application rather than the weeks of intensive checks that we mere mortals need to subject ourselves to.
The whole plan is so intensely half-baked that his minions are still in the process of writing the application the following morning, while he's sitting in front of the orphanarium manager.

I never suggested the plan was complex. If anything, the adoption process makes the plan even more complex.

@shim - It's a plan that involves him tricking a moronic orphanage inspector and three small girls. Evidently only a few hours of thought went into the planning, less time than he spent outside Vector's fortress the day before.
